# Chrome run by Selenium doesn't advance farther than mazimizing the browser window

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying run a test searching for tents on eBay, but the test stops after maximizing the window

```
package com.xxx.yyy;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class eBay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        mySleep(3);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        String url = "www.ebay.com";
        driver.get(url);
        driver.findElement(By.className("gh-tb ui-autocomplete-input"));
        WebElement textbox = driver.findElement(By.id("gh-ac-box"));
        textbox.sendKeys("tent");
        mySleep(1);
        driver.quit();
    }

    private static void mySleep(int t) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(t * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The Chrome window opens, is maximized, but nothing happens next and in Eclipse, I can see this error:

> INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument

Comment: Which line is the exception on? Generally if the browser comes up and doesn't navigate, it means that your browser version and browser driver versions are out of sync. Check that and report back.

Comment: My Chrome version is the latest - 75.0.3770.100. How can I find out, what my  browser driver version is? Besides, it worked before on another website...